# Multiple WebSockets : large media streams delay receipt of latency sensitive normal messages

Tags: websocket, latency

I'm making an multi-user app that sends messages between users using a websocket.
The socket is working great for now. I want to add the possibility to send large file over this websocket over clients.

The first test was to send my messages and some files at the same time on this socket. However, I would have to wait for the socket to send the file before sending any other messages. Those messages can be latency sensitive (I need them the fatest I could).

I was wondering if it's a good solution to open another websocket to send those huge files, and not delay the latency sensitive messages as declared in this question : [Multiple websocket connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247971/multiple-websocket-connections/9269458#9269458)

I saw in many other questions that having multiple websockets will change nothing as it will be my bandwith that will be limiting the througput after all. I was wondering if I can have 2 websockets : one fore large files and the other for latency sensitive messages, and hope that they will "auto-balance". By "auto-balance" I mean that both socket will have 50% of bandwith each (or something like that). I would have my latency sensitive message while getting the file in another websocket (getting the file delayed is not a problem).

If you have any insight about this, I'm all ears.
Thanks in advance.